# Pass int array in where clause of LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, generics

There is a class

```
Public class Student
{
  int id;
  int rollNum;
  String Name;
}
```

a method

```
Public List<Student> GetAllStudents()
{
  var studentList = GetMeAll(); // Simple select * query to get all students
  //unfortunately i can't make changes in this method so have to write a linq query to       //filter data.
  //getting int array ids correctly from some method
   var filterList = FilterStudentsByID(ids,StudentList);
}
```

I want to write a method that takes an int array as input and returns a List

```
Public List<Student> FilterStudentsByID(int[] ids,List<student> studentList)
{
  //There should be a linq query , but I am new to linq so don't know how to write this.
  Var list = from  studentList in ..... don't know much;
}
```

Any help in writing the query. Thank you all for Answers, I am also looking for maintain the performances  with large list of records ?? It will be great if you can add me simple explanation of the query will work internally ??

Comment: Does each student have a unique ID?

Comment: Also: Will the list of ids be long (more than 5% of the size of the student list, say)? Just trying to work out if it's worth creating a list of students sorted by ID before doing the searching.

Comment: yes it could be going around 5% of the size

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are looking to find those students from the list whose id's are present in the `ids` array then:

```
var list = from s in stundentList
           where ids.Contains(s.ID)
           select s;
```

Comment: Can you explain me how this will work internally ,like will it hamper performance in case of large list??

Comment: Looks like it would be O(N*M) where N = student count, M = ID count. But you can't do much better, I think.

Comment: @ankur, LINQ internally uses iteration, so it will check against each student id against the id array. This is useful when interacting with the database, since that will create a `Select * from table where ID in (1,2,3)` kind of query. More details on http://wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/

Comment: Unfortunately it won't be executed on the database in this case, as "studentList" is a List and not an IQueryable.

Comment: @JustAnotherUserYouMayKnow, yes that is in the question

Comment: Am I the only one that cannot use Contains on any sort of INT, SHORT, LONG, etc... Just strings, unless it is IQueryable. It wasn't mention in the question...

Answer (score 5):

try

```
Var list = studentList.Where(s=>ids.Contains(s.id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answers already given will be fast enough, but *just in case* after testing you find that it's too slow: You can try converting the student list to a dictionary before doing the searching.

*You should only use this after careful timing tests*, since it is likely to be a lot slower for most cases!

```
public static List<Student> FilteredStudents(int[] targetIds)
{
    var allStudents = GetAllStudents().ToDictionary(student => student.id);
    var result = new List<Student>();

    foreach (int id in targetIds)
    {
        Student student;

        if (allStudents.TryGetValue(id, out student))
        {
            result.Add(student);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```