# Writing a method to be used as IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to write this method:

```
   public IQueryable<String> FilterIp(Boolean filter)
        {
            return filter ? ((IEnumerable<String>)_filterIp).Select(x => x).AsQueryable() : ((IEnumerable<String>)new String[0]).Select(x => x).AsQueryable();

        }
 String[] _filterIp = new[] { "191.16.95.133", "::1", "127.0.0.1" };
```

and then wan to use it like this:

```
.Where(ip => !FilterIp(filtered).Contains(ip)).ToList()
```

The problem is that I get an error:

> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.String] FilterIp(Boolean)' method,
>   and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: FilterIP is not a recognized SQL method.  So you are going to need to pull the entities local first.

Comment: Store the result of `FilterIp(filtered)` in a variable first and use the variable in your query.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks, please post an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, it's enough to do this

```
var filterIp = filter 
                  ? new[] { "191.16.95.133", "::1", "127.0.0.1" }
                  : new string[0];

var query = <body>.Where(ip => !filterIp.Contains(ip));
```

but I don't know whether `FilterIp()` is in some other component. If so, it would be enough for it to contain the first line of code above.

If the value of `filter` is known 'close' to the query you can also do

```
IQueryable<YourClass> query = <body>;
if (filter)
    query = query.Where(ip => !filterIp.Contains(ip));
```

where `filterIp` is just the array of IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use IQueryable? Just use the array itself:

```
.Where(ip => !_filterIp.Contains(ip)).ToList();
```

You might want to look into a similar stockoverflow question:
[Pass int array in where clause of LINQ Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380774/pass-int-array-in-where-clause-of-linq-query)